# rdlc report in vs2010, how do i repeat tables header on every page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

Hi all I am making rdlc report.

In report I am using more than one dataset.

Also, I am using more than one tables.

Different tables having diff dataset.

I need to repeat all those tables in second page for second record.

How can I achieve this thing?

Answer (score 1):

Select the tablix you have created -> `Properties` -> in the section `Column Header` check the option `Repeat header columns on each page`
You can do the same for the row header if you have one